# Установка pip для python3.9

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code, pip, python-3.9

я установил pip, но он не работает. Программа visual studio code его просто не видит. Я для проверки через терминал решил запустить код, если для запуска писал python3.9 "name file", то была ошибка, опять же просто не видит pip, НО если запускал через python3 , то все работало, подскажите как установить pip именно для версии 3.9? Использую linux ubuntu, IDE visual studio code, python3.9, pip20.0.2. [image: На скрине видно, что pip установлен, но python3.9 его не видит]

Comment: Сразу говорю, в python я только начал работать, поэтому ошибка может быть самая банальная и простая. Заранее спасибо всем за ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Я что-то совсем затупил :D
Решение этого совсем простое. Если кто-то затупил как и я, то вот вам решение:

```
python3.9(можете вместо 3.9 указать свою версию) -m pip install ...
```

Comment: А просто `python` не пашет?